# What does this recursion function output?

Tags: recursion

I'm just starting to learn recursion and I don't understand the output, which is 39493. Could you explain?

```
struct Node {
int value;
Node* next;
}
```

head --> 3 --> 9 --> 4 --> NULL

---

```
 void f4(Node* n) {
 if(n == NULL)
 return;

 if(n->next == NULL)
 cout << n->value << “ ”;
 else {
 cout << n->value << “ ”;
 f4(n->next);
 cout << n->value << “ ”;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `f4` function prints out a linked list of integers, forwards (from the head/root to the tail) and then backwards. It does this because the inner call of `f4` within the `else` clause is surrounded by two `cout` statements, which will both print the current node's value, adding a stack frame (new execution context with the next node) in between. The last node (the tail) is captured by `if(n->next == NULL)`, and there's only one `cout` statement in this clause, so the tail only prints once.

I added a `main` method to illustrate this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Node {
    int value;
    Node* next;
};

void f4(Node* n) {
    // This will never be reached
    // except if f4 is called with NULL directly
    if(n == NULL)
        return;

    if(n->next == NULL)
        cout << n->value << endl;
    else {
        cout << n->value << endl;
        f4(n->next);
        cout << n->value << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    cout << "Starting!" << endl;

    Node n1 = {1, 0};
    Node n2 = {2, &n1};
    Node n3 = {3, &n2};

    // get pointer to n3 -> n2 -> n1 
    f4(&n3);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Starting!
3
2
1
2
3
```

To understand the stack frame (recursive call) handling mechanism:
https://www.bottomupcs.com/elements_of_a_process.xhtml.

You might understand it better by adding additional markers to differentiate the `cout << n->value << endl` on different lines.

Comment: You helped a lot Thanks!